# How to use CMake to include a library, then include its headers using angled brackets in source file?

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, openni, nite

I used homebrew to install opencv and openni and nite.

and I've managed to make a cmake file for opencv, and somehow it already had a defined path for its directory OpenCV_LIBS, not sure how or where I find out about that.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( main )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( main main.cpp )

target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

After installing [toktakke's build](https://github.com/totakke/homebrew-openni) openni and nite.
I gave this a shot, and extended to the following, and again I'm not sure where I'd find these aliases to their directories.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( main )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OPENNI_INCLUDE})
Include_directories(${NITE_INCLUDE})
add_executable( main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${OPENNI_LIB} ${NITE_LIB} )
```

but it wasn't integrated well

in `.bash_profile` I have the following:

```
export OPENNI_INCLUDE="/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10/include/ni"
export OPENNI_LIB="/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10/lib"
export OPENNI_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10"
export NITE_INCLUDE="/usr/local/Cellar/nite/1.5.2.21/include/nite"
export NITE_LIB="/usr/local/Cellar/nite/1.5.2.21/lib"
export NITE_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/nite/1.5.2.21"
```

now I get the following error:

```
fatal error: 'XnOpenNI.h' file not found
#include <XnOpenNI.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the

```
include_directories($ENV{OPENNI_INCLUDE})
```

after your project definition. This will add the path to the OPENNI include files as an -I option to the compiler.  More about the 'include_directories' command is [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:include_directories).

Regarding the origin of OpenCV_LIBS:

When the 'find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )' is used, cmake will automatically call the FindOpenCV.cmake (found in the path specified by CMAKE_MODULE_PATH variable). The FindOpenCV.cmake is responsible for actually locate the OpenCV libraries and include files and define both the OpenCV_LIBS and bunch of other variables.

This makes it "magically" available for you. More info about find_package magic could be found in the [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_package)

Comment: What if the namespace openni is still not recognized? and neither are the classes in the openni library (like Device, or OpenNI::initialize(), or OpenNI::shutdown())

Comment: I'm not an expert in OpenNI but probably you are including the wrong file. For C++ interfaces you should include  XnCppWrapper.h if I'm not mistaken.